# Android RecyclerView best practice

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an page that looks like this:

```
A line of text
A list of items
Some more lines of text
Another list of items
```

Currently my XML layout is as follows:

```
<TextView/>
<RecyclerView/>
<TextView/>
<TextView/>
<RecyclerView/>
```

I'm wondering if it wouldn't be better to have only one RecyclerView with different view types, instead of all of this. What is considered best, and why?

I am quite new to Android development, sorry if this question is not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use two RecyclerViews because you have two lists.  Putting everything into one will force all the items in list #1 to be scrolled before seeing the items that follow, including the second list.